# Live streaming using android Device

Tags: android, streaming

I have been working on an android app that streams videos live on a server using android built-in camera and anyone can watch that live stream from my website which is deployed on the server.
So can any one help me on how should i start working on my project because at present i have no direction to start with.
More specific example is:-
Like a person goes to a picnic and he wants his friends and family to see whats going on with the tour and his family can see live what he's doing live.....

Answer (score 2):

There is an open-source project that does a very similar thing:
http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/

It basically uses the LocalSocket of the camera to read the video and stream it from a webserver. You should be able to find lots of information in the source code.

If you want to stream over the internet, for everyone to see i can recommend you the service justin.tv which lets you broadcast you stream to the whole internet. If tried it, and it works very good!

However, if there's no wifi you will probably have a very laggy connection, unless you convert the video in a smaller size...